# Java: Why does my List contain different types? (Filtering Lists)

Tags: java, list, casting, instanceof

The whole time I thought, if I am using a List like `List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>()` all items in this list are of Type `Thing`. Yesterday i was taught the other way.

I've created the following stuff and wonder why it is like it is.

An Interface `Thing`

```
public interface Thing {
  String getType();

  String getName();
}
```

A class `ObjectA`

```
public class ObjectA implements Thing {
  private static final String TYPE = "Object A";
  private String name;

  public ObjectA(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("ObjectA{");
    sb.append("name='").append(name).append('\'');
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public String getType() {
    return TYPE;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  // equals and hashCode + getter and setter
}
```

A class `ObjectB`

```
public class ObjectB implements Thing {
  private static final String TYPE = "Object B";
  private String name;
  private int value1;
  private String value2;
  private boolean value3;

  public ObjectB(String name, int value1, String value2, boolean value3) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
    this.value3 = value3;
  }

  @Override
  public String getType() {
    return TYPE;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("ObjectB{");
    sb.append("name='").append(name).append('\'');
    sb.append(", value1=").append(value1);
    sb.append(", value2='").append(value2).append('\'');
    sb.append(", value3=").append(value3);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }

  // equals and hashCode + getter and setter
}
```

The `main` method

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>();
    final ObjectA objA = new ObjectA("Thing 1");
    final ObjectB objB = new ObjectB("Thing 2", 123, "extra", true);

    things.add(objA);
    things.add(objB);

    // The List doesn't contain Thing entities, it contains ObjectA and ObjectB entities
    System.out.println(things);

    for(final Thing thing : things) {
      if (thing instanceof ObjectA) {
        System.out.println("Found Object A: " + thing);
        final ObjectA object = (ObjectA) thing;
      }
      if (thing instanceof ObjectB) {
        System.out.println("Found Object B: " + thing);
      }
    }
  }
```

The output of this method is:

```
[ObjectA{name='Thing 1'}, ObjectB{name='Thing 2', value1=123, value2='extra', value3=true}]
```

So i assume i've `ObjectA` entities and `ObjectB` entities in my `List<Thing>`.

**Question:** Can someone provide a link (or some keywords which can be used for searching), which explain this behavior, or can explain it to me?

**additional Question:** I've started to filter this `List<Thing>` with `instanceof` but i have read instanceof and casting are bad practice (e.g. no good model design). Is the are "good" way to filter this List for all Types of `ObjectA` to perform only on these objects some operations?

Comment: `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` ARE instances of `Thing` - This is polymorphism in action

Comment: You don't need filtering. If you don't want `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` in the same collection, don't put them there. If you do put them there, make sure they can be used without caring about which implementation they are, i.e. just consider them `Things`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone provide a link (or some keywords which can be used for searching), which explain this behavior, or can explain it to me?

This behaviour is called "polymorphism". Basically, since `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` implements `Thing`, instances of `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` can be used like a `Thing` object. In your code, you added them to a list that can contain `Thing` objects.

Note how even if those objects are now of (compile time) type `Thing`, at runtime they still know what they are. When you call `toString` on them, the respective overridden `toString` methods in `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` will be called. It is as if the `Thing` "morphs" into `ObjectA` or `ObjectB`.

> Is the are "good" way to filter this List for all Types of ObjectA to perform only on these objects some operations?

The reason why people say this is bad practice is because if you want to do different things depending whether the object is `ObjectA` or `ObjectB`, why did you make them implement `Thing` and make a list of `Thing` to store them? You could have just used a `List<Object>`. The real advantage of using `List<Thing>` is that you *avoid* knowing what actual objects are in there when you are working with the list. All you know is that the things inside the list implement `Thing` and you can call methods declared in `Thing`.

So if you need to filter the list to separate the two types, you could have just created two lists to store them in the first place. One for `ObjectA` and one for `ObjectB`. Obviously, this is not always possible, especially if the list comes from somewhere else (like a external library). In that case, your current code is fine.

Comment: I've a note to your sentence: "Note how even if those objects are now of (compile time) type Thing ...". If i do the following in Idea IntelliJ `Thing thing1 = new ObjectB("Thing 2", 123, "extra", true);` I've access to all methods like `thing1.getValue3()`. So it seems even at 'compile time' its not a `Thing`. It's a ObjectB, or am i missing something?

Comment: @SleepyX667 You can't have access to `getValue3` in that case. Did you cast it or anything?

Comment: '@Sweeper' I'm sorry. This is my fault. I got the list of methods in the dropbox (so i assume i've access to them) but when i press enter IntelliJ makes a cast.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid instanceof check in your additional question example. When you work with List items, it should be sufficient to have interface methods available. If you need to do something with only ObjectA or ObjectB, I suggest to use another List with only ObjectA or ObjectB. For example you can define different methods to do Thing specific job and ObjectB specific job:

```
public void processThings(List<Thing> things) {

        for(final Thing thing : things) {

            // we work only with methods that provided by interface Thing
            System.out.println(thing.getType());
            System.out.println(thing.getName());

        }
    }

public void processObjectsB(List<ObjectB> objectsB) {

        // here we do some specific things with only B objects, 
        // assuming class ObjectB has an additional method doSomeSpecificB()
        for(final ObjectB objectB : objectsB) {

            objectB.doSomeSpecificB();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you please add some example source code to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

I have a garden that contains potatoes, carrots and broccoli.  I have a very strict rule - I won't plant anything in the garden that I can't eat.  So no poison ivy here!

So this is a `Garden<Edible>` - everything I plant in the garden has to be edible.

Now `class Potato implements Edible` means that every potato is edible.  But it also means that I can plant a potato in my garden.  Likewise, `class Carrot implements Edible` - all carrots are edible, and I'm allowed to plant carrots.

It's a dark night, and I'm hungry.  I go out to my garden and put my hand on something in the garden.  I can't see what it is, but I know that everything in my garden is edible.  So I pull it out of the garden, and take it inside to cook and eat.  It doesn't matter what I've grabbed - I know it will be something I can eat.

Because this is a `Garden<Edible>`.  It may or may not contain `Potato` objects.  It may or may not contain `Broccoli` objects.  It does not contain `PoisonIvy` objects.

Now, translate that all to your example.  You have `class ObjectA implements Thing` - which means that every `ObjectA` is a `Thing`.  You have `class ObjectB implements Thing` - which means that every `ObjectB` is a `Thing`.  And you have a `List<Thing>` - a `List` that can contain `ObjectA` objects, `ObjectB` objects, and any other object of any class  that `implements Thing`.  What you can't  put in it is an object of any class that *doesn't* implement `Thing`.

Comment: Nice example! But you might need an overidable `cook` method because I assume it should be different between `Potato` and `Broccoli`, not speaking of `Tomato`...

Answer (score 1):

`things` is a `List<Thing>`. That means that at compile time, Java will ensure that any object that you write to `things` **is** a `Thing`. As `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` both implement `Thing` the actual *implementation* of any member of `things` can be `ObjectA` or `ObjectB`. This is *by design* and that feature is called *polymorphism*: object of different classes share a common interface and can be accessed thrrough that interface independently of their actual type. For example you could use:

```
for(final Thing thing : things) {
    System.stdout.println("Found a " + thing.getType() + " named " + thing.getName());
}
```

Using `instanceof` and casting is not necessarily bad practice and can have correct use case. But it is often a hint that the hierachy of classes and interfaces has not been properly designed. Ideally, if you have to process a `Thing`, you should not wonder about its actual class: you have a `Thing`, and using `Thing` methods should be enough.

In that sense, `instanceof` is at the same level as reflection is: it is a low level tool that allows to see what is hidden under the hood. And any time you use it, you should ask you whether polymorphism could not be enough.